# AppFabric 1.1 and Windows 8 Consumer Preview

Tags: windows-8, appfabric

I got a new laptop for my job and was thinking about installing Win8 CP as my main operating system, I love it, so I tried to do some tests in a VM to see if AppFabric cache can work in Win8 CP. The official response from MS is "AppFabric is not supported in Win8 and we would tell you how to run it when Win8 is released" and of course that is not a nice answer for me, so I tried... and failed...

After installing .Net 3.5SP1 and latest updates AppFabric cache was installed and configured without any problem in my Win8 machine using my local user and a XML provider in a shared folder, I gave permissions and everything to that folder...

The first problem is that the Cache Administrator Console answer back with this message every time I open it:

```
Use-CacheCluster : ErrorCode<ERRCAdmin040>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Failed to connect
to hosts in the cluster At line:1 char:46
   + Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration;Use-CacheCluster
   +                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Use-CacheCluster], DataCacheException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Commands.UseCacheClusterCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Well, looks like something is not right... let's try to start the cache cluster

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> start-cachecluster

HostName : CachePort Service Name            Service Status Version Info
-------------------- ------------            -------------- ------------
win8:22233           AppFabricCachingService UP             0 [0,0][0,0]


PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

The version info answer is not right at all, so problably create a new cache would fail

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> new-cache IPE
New-Cache : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-cache IPE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Cache], NullReferenceExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Applicat
   ionServer.Caching.Commands.NewCacheCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

And pretty much that's all...

I tried everything I could find in the internet:

- Starting the Remote
- Registry Service Modifying the host file in windows/system32/drivers/etc/host to place an explicit entry to localhost and my machine name
- Checking permissions
- Installing updates
- Opening firewall rules

(For the firewall rules I tried something like this)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Server AppFabric: AppFabric Caching Service" new enable=Yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Remote Service Management (RPC)" profile=domain new enable=Yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Remote Service Management (RPC-EPMAP)" profile=domain new enable=Yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Remote Service Management (NP-In)" profile=domain new enable=Yes
```

And still getting the same problem... I have no idea where to start or continue to fix the problem... I would really appreciate any help, and yes, would be really really hard for me to wait until Win8 official release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start the Remote Registry service, if not started. AppFabric uses this service even to connect to your local machine
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/e977c98d-32e6-4b58-8947-6248cdcf5020)